# Accessing the Deserialized JSON list's values and modifying the null values

Tags: apex, integration, json, rest, webservices

I have deserialized a JSON data into a list.I want to access the null values present in the list for any wrapper variables and modify it to an empty string.

Deserialization Code:

`lstSeeds = (List<WebserviceWrapper>)JSON.deserialize(JSONData, List<WebserviceWrapper>.class);`

My JSON Data:

`{Order":"Pending",                                                            "RequestedDeliveryDate":"2023-07-12T18:30:00"                                  "Account Name":null}`

I have successly deserialized it into list but I want to replace Account Name: null to Account Name : "" so that the data gets reflected in my LWC Component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could preprocess the JSON data like this

```
lstSeeds = (List<WebserviceWrapper>)JSON.deserialize(
            JSONData.replace('"Account Name":null','"Account Name":""'),
            List<WebserviceWrapper>.class);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the thing is ,I have around 40 wrapper variables and I don't want to go to each variable and explicitly add a null check and then replace.Any other way where we can dynamically check those variables values?

Comment: https://iwritecrappycode.wordpress.com/2014/07/16/stripping-nulls-from-a-json-object-in-apex/

Maybe check this article out, you might have to change a bit of the logic to add the empty string tho :)

Comment: Hey @NedlaV, Thanks for your reply. I tweaked the answer given by @/cropredy above and it's working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to manually parse the JSON and add your value.

Have a look at this thread : [Parse JSON with Apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/262947/parse-json-with-apex)